# Import Database from PhPMyAdmin to Android

Tags: android, database, phpmyadmin

I am developing an android app. I have just developed a website for the same purpose.(**Using PHP**)

Now the database is ready in **PhpMyAdmin** with data and I want to import the entire database in android app(as an **sqlite** database).

PS : I have knowledge of PhpMyAdmin , sqlite in Android and good knowledge in android. The database is not too large.

Answer (score 0):

First thing come to my mind is,you can use use JSch to execute ssh commands in Java.Then you can use ssh mysqldump command http://www.rogerobeid.com/2011/02/06/mysqldump-over-ssh/ to execute mysqldump to open a pipe to your phone.

Comment: Isn't that any tool or extension to convert?

As I don't know these commands.

Comment: If you dont want to do that,first you want to convert your mysql database to sqlite type http://livecode.byu.edu/database/mysql-sqliteExport.php .Then you can open a file stream to that file if you have a web site contains that database like "FileInputStream is = new URL("http://yoursite.com/yourdatabase").openStream();" then you can fetch the database file.

Comment: I got the first half of the conversion. Can you provide any tutorial of demo for the second half of your answer?